# 403 Forbidden on large $_POST array in PHP on Apache

Tags: php, apache, forms

When I post a large form using POST method to PHP running on Apache, I get `403 Forbidden` error from the server. If I lower the number of form fields to 251, it works perfectly. I have changed `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`, etc. to 64 MB but I can see no change at all.

Comment: Please be careful with spelling, capitalization and formatting. By making your questions easier to read and understand you’ll attract more answerers and possibly get more upvotes. I tagged your question with [tag:apache] and [tag:html-form] (and its more frequent variant [tag:forms]) as those are the technologies directly involved in your problem. Some rewording was needed to reduce unnecessary fluff and get to the core faster.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using < PHP 5.3.9

PHP 5.3.9 introduced the `max_input_vars` config option, which is defaulted to a value of 1000. Check out the [Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) section of the PHP manual. The default value and the change log are at the top of the page.

The value can be changed by updating the server's php.ini, adding an .htaccess file, or [adding a line to httpd.conf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Comment: The posted form contains only 750 fields . I have updated the php.ini file for max_input_vars to 5000, post_max_size to 128M,upload_max_filesize to 128M etc. But there is still issues with the form POST values. The same 403 forbidden is returned from apache. I have searched and found some pages showing this issue relating to apache mod_security and LImitRequestBody .@Umair